# How to setup FreeSSHd with Jenkins?

Tags: windows-7, jenkins, freesshd

I have Jenkins on CentOS and want to run commands remotely on Windows 7. I managed to set it up for transferring files but when executing commands I always get:

```
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [.../some.exe
] ...
AllowDesktopAccess failed.
Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.
```

Currently FreeSSHd is running as a service and I'm logging in with Windows auth.

I am also able to run ssh from shell from the machine Jenkins is on and execute commands remotely. It's just Jenkins that seem to have problems...

Comment: Have you tried a simple uncheck of freeSSHD settings->SSH->Use new console engine ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately didn't help and broken connections with putty.

Comment: freeSSHD is really really buggy, ever though about using cygwin and opensshd?